# ANDROID: wait until the activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is completed

Tags: android

I integrate a java photo application into a windev application using a luncher like this:

```
    public static String lunchPhotoGeniusScan(final String path, final Context context,String key){
        Luncher.context = context;
        ImageFiltersActivity.isSaved = false;
        clearAllPages();

        String returnValue = NO_IMAGE;

        try {
            initSDK(key);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanActivity.PATH, path);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (LicenseException e) {
            returnValue = KEY_ERROR;
        }

        return returnValue;

    }
```

And I need to know when my throwing activity is over and be able to recover a photo path taken with the throwing activity.

Comment: convert to english plz

Comment: Hi welcome to SO . This is a English Only QA site so please post your question in English . because I don't think it has a French version..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is an English-only website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have a simple solution with callBack :

```
public interface CallBackGeniusScan {
    void onFinish(String codeRetour,String resultat);
}

  public static boolean lunchPhotoGeniusScan(final String path, final Context context, String key, CallBackGeniusScan callBack){
        Luncher.context = context;
        ImageFiltersActivity.isSaved = false;
        clearAllPages();

        boolean returnValue = true;

        try {
            initSDK(key);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanActivity.PATH, path);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // instance callBack
            GeniusScanApplication.callBack = callBack;

        } catch (LicenseException e) {
            returnValue = false;
        }

        return returnValue;

    }
```

and when i call the luncher i do this :

```
       final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        CallBackGeniusScan callBack = new CallBackGeniusScan() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish(String codeRetour,String resultat) {
                // My CallBack Code
            }
        };

        lancerPhotoGeniusScan(path,MainActivity.this,myKey,callBack);

    }
```

And when i finish my last Activity i do that :

```
GeniusScanApplication.callBack.onFinish(GeniusScanApplication.IMAGE_OK,GeniusScanApplication.imgPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty to start activity with result

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: The problem is for integer android code in windev mobile app, i use ApplicationContext and lunchPhotoGeniusScan is a static method for call in the windev app